# SQL Server query In clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server query which is supposed to select those first week and third week login to our portal but didn't login at second week. My problem is, the query below taking about 15 secs to be loaded. Is there any faster way or any problem on my query ?

```
select 
    count(distinct id ) 
from 
    table_x
where 
    g in (319, 329) 
    and enable = 1 
    and Date between '2016-01-18' and '2016-01-24'  --Third Week
    and id in (select distinct id 
               from table_x
               where g in (319, 329) 
                 and enable = 1 
                 and Date between '2016-01-05' and '2016-01-11' --First Week
                 and id not in (select distinct id 
                                from table_x
                                where g in (319, 329) 
                                  and enable = 1 
                                  and Date between '2016-01-11' and '2016-01-17' --Second Week
                               )
              )
```

Comment: What is the execution plan of your query? How big are the tables? What index do you have?

Comment: "select distinct" is an expensive operation. Learn when to use "select distinct" and when not to use it. It does **NOT assist performance** in this query. `tip` ID is normally unique in a table, so "select distinct [id]" is a waste of effort.

Comment: - The table is more than mil records.
- Actually the ID is not unique ID but user ID. sorry for miss guiding...

Answer (score 2):

Try using conditional aggregates (a single where clause and summing 3 case expressions) instead of multiple passes through the table.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(*)
FROM (
      SELECT
            user_id
          , SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-24' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [ThirdWeek]
          , SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-11' AND '2016-01-17' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [SecondWeek]
          , SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-05' AND '2016-01-11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [FirstWeek]
      FROM table_x
      WHERE x1.g IN (319, 329)
            AND x1.enable = 1
            AND x1.[Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-05' AND '2016-01-24'
      GROUP BY
            user_id
) d
WHERE [FirstWeek] > 0
      AND [ThirdWeek] > 0
      AND [SecondWeek] = 0
```

While I would expect the above to be a good option, perhaps use of EXISTS/NOT EXISTS could help, note you do NOT need distinct in the following example.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM table_x x1
WHERE x1.g IN (319, 329)
      AND x1.enable = 1
      AND x1.[Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-24'  --Third Week
      AND EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  NULL
            FROM table_x
            WHERE g IN (319, 329)
                  AND enable = 1
                  AND Date BETWEEN '2016-01-05' AND '2016-01-11' --First Week
                  AND x1.user_id = table_x.user_id
      )
      AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  NULL
            FROM table_x
            WHERE g IN (319, 329)
                  AND enable = 1
                  AND Date BETWEEN '2016-01-11' AND '2016-01-17' --Second Week
                  AND x1.user_id = table_x.user_id
      )
;
```